# Moving the javascript code to design view is not working. Only code-behind Attributes.Add("onclick" works. Puzzled

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onclick, code-behind

I wanted to disable a button after it is clicked and at the same time fire the post back event to generate a report. My first set of code did not work because soon after the button is disabled the page won't submit/post back. here's the first set of code which was not implemented. the onclientclick calls a javascript function which has these lines

document.getElementById('btnGenerateReport').disabled=true;
GetPostBackEventReference(btnGenerateReport,'');

since it was not posting back

i tried the following on page_load code behind

```
btnGenerateReport.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.disabled=true;" + ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnGenerateReport, ""))
```

that worked well. but I tried to copy the javascript that got generated and pasted directly on design view

```
onclick="this.disabled=true;__doPostBack('btnDownloadClientsWithConviction','');"
```

its not working from client side alone after I disable the code behind attributes.add
but when I check the view source the 2 pages are the same

why am I not able to move the code from code-behind to design view?

Answer (score 1):

Because the Button.ClientId is generated using a [NamingContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx).

Try this instead:

```
document.getElementById('<%= btnGenerateReport.ClientId %>').disabled=true; 
GetPostBackEventReference('<%= btnGenerateReport.ClientId %>','');
```

Comment: well rick schott, I checked the clientid before writing the code and the client id generated is same as the id in design view. only in certain situations asp.net create a different client id different from the id in design view. for eg: controls inside user controls.

Comment: Depends on if you are using run="server" or .NET 4 ClientId options.